# Finding a class element in a group of buttons in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to make two buttons behave in a similar fashion to radio buttons, where only one can be selected at a time.

HTML

```
<button class="button" value="purchase" name="selector_button_group">
      Purchase
</button>
<button class="button" value="refinance" name="selector_button_group">
      Refinance
</button>
```

jQuery

```
$("button[name=selector_button_group]").click(function() {
  $("button[name=selector_button_group]").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Now getting back the value of the selected button

```
var purchaseType =  $("button[name=selector_button_group].active").val();
```

or

```
var purchaseType =  $("button[name=selector_button_group]").hasClass('active').val();
```

However this doesn't work and will not return the button with the class active.  I have also tried using `hasClass('active')` but I cannot figure out how to get this to find the active button with it.

Comment: why exactly are you using buttons instead of radio buttons

Comment: where/when is `purchaseType` defined and used?

Comment: purchaseType is used when a save button is clicked and the form is posted

Comment: I have to chime in with Pabs123. This just seems like you want the look to be button:ish, but the behavior to be radio buttons. Just style the radio buttons like buttons (or hide the actual `input` and style the labels) and use the HTML that's intended for this type of thing. It's called semantics, accessibility and progressive enhancement. This won't work for visitors where JS doesn't execute (for whatever reason).

Comment: works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k70pbsem/). You might need to show more code, like the event handler that you set / use purchaseType in. Also `.hasClass()` returns a boolean value so you cant chain `.val()` to it

Comment: Wow I ended up having a typo in my code for purchase type and was referencing it incorrectly I had purchase_type, the code I had was working and I only realized it after I tried the fiddle.  Sorry for the inconvenience I have been up for way too long and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working as is, see it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgpYKP)

If that is not working and you want to keep the same code structure as you currently have try changing:

```
$("button[name=selector_button_group].active").val();
```

To:

```
$("button[name=selector_button_group].active").attr('value');
```

You could also use `.text()` as previously suggested, but this solution will allow you to change the value so that it is not the same as the text if you so wish.

Comment: my code was working, I had a spelling error when I was using the variable purchaseType, thanks for the help and the fiddle helped point it out

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: Why? His buttons have `value="purchase"` and `value="refinance"`, I think that's what he wants to get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set value of `purchaseType` at the right time and to the exact thing you want.

```js
var purchaseType;

$("button[name=selector_button_group]").click(function() {
  $("button[name=selector_button_group]").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  purchaseType = $(this).text();
  console.log(purchaseType);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Finding a class element in a group of buttons in JQuery</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button class="button" value="purchase" name="selector_button_group">
      Purchase
</button>
<button class="button" value="refinance" name="selector_button_group">
      Refinance
</button>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function, so:

```
$("button[name=selector_button_group]").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings('.button')
        .removeClass('active');

    var val = $("button[name=selector_button_group].active").text();
});
```